# Is it okay to use "software" after version number?

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns

> The possible functional effect of the single nucleotide variations (SNVs) was assessed using the PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5 **software**.

Since "software" is a noncount noun, and "v1.3.5" clearly indicates a specific version, it is okay to use "software" here, or it would be better to use "program"?

> The possible functional effect of the single nucleotide variations (SNVs) was assessed using the PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5 **program**.

Comment: In any case, program sounds better. Though I share your concerns, I think the first sentence should have *a piece of* before software.

Comment: Why you didn't say: software PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5. However, if the software is well-known, I think, you can omit the **software** and simply say: **PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5**

Comment: other possible variants: PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5 package/utility/suite, whetever applies to the sofware best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a version number might be considered part of the name of the software, and in that case, one would not use the definite article or a noun after the proper noun.

> Windows 2.0 is a crowd-pleaser.

<sup>unidiomatic</sup> The Windows 2.0 is a crowd-pleaser.
<sup>marginal</sup> The Windows 2.0 O/S is a crowd-pleaser.
<sup>unidiomatic</sup> Windows 2.0 O/S is a crowd-pleaser.

A version with subversion is not really the software's *name* but a sort of post-positioned determiner, and so we would not use the definite article with the version/subversion:

<sup>unidiomatic</sup>... using the PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5 software.

idiomatic spoken English:

> ... using PolyPhen version 1 dot 3 dot 5.
>
> ... using version 1.3.5 of the PolyPhen software.
>
> ... using version 1.3.5 of PolyPhen

But how one *writes* this may fall under the jurisdiction of the house style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I've read it shifting the words:

> The possible functional effect of the single nucleotide variations (SNVs) was assessed using the software PolyPhen-2 v1.3.5.

(please notice that I'm not a native English speaker)